# learning C#, need help understanding this code

Tags: c#, arrays, function, for-loop

I am learning C# and I came to this "for" function and something really bothers me about it:

```
 int[] arrayNumbers = new int[numberAmmount];
// take "numberAmmount" as 5 so numberAmmount = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberAmmount; i++)
            {
            Console.Write("{0} Number: ", i + 1);
            numberAmmount[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
```

Isn't "i++" in for function the same i as in the Console.Write "i + 1"

Shouldn't i after the first cycle be 2?
and after the second cycle be 4 because of the i + 1 in console.write???

Basically I am trying to get in a number from the user which will be the amount of numberAmmount and by this for function i give every numberAmmount[x] a value and then have my program decide the highest and the lowest number but I don't understand why the i + 1 doesn't add an extra 1

edit: got it thanks

Comment: no, `i++` means `i += 1`, or `i = i + 1`

Comment: i++ changes the value of i.  i+1 does not.

Comment: When you do `i + 1` you are not assigning the new value back to `i`. However, when you do `i++` this is a convenient shorthand for `i = i + 1`.

Comment: @granadaCoder So basically i + 1 doesnt change the value? only i++ in for function does right?

Comment: Come on you all, I think we can be a bit gentler here.

Comment: @MarcoMagdolen, no.. `i + 1` simply adds `i` and `1` together without assigning it. However, doing `i ++` or `i += 1` or `i = i + 1` (which all do the same thing) will change the value of i to add one

Comment: No, `i+1` does not increment (change) the value of `i`, as `i++` does.  It just takes the value of `i`, adds one to it, and "uses" that calculated value in the `Console.Write()` function.

Comment: *Please* start by reading an introductory C# book or article online. Start from the bottom rather than jumping in and assuming behavior.

Comment: Okay  I got it now! Thank you so much peeps :) :D

Comment: note that ++i will increment it BEFORE is "uses" it.

Comment: @DangerZone got a physical book, 70 pages in and I came to this and I couldnt figure it out no worries iam fine :)

Comment: @granadaCoder good to know lol thanks

Comment: The summation in the `Console.Write()` call doesn't change the current value of 1.  The result of `i + 1` is independently fed into the `Console.Write` call.  `i++` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`, not `i + 1`.

Comment: @KirkWoll No I don't want to be gentle... SO has started to be the place to ask a question without making a reasearch or reading the course material...

Comment: I know. But I think we can at times be a bit more civil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `i + 1` does not have an assignment operator. That code is printing the value of i plus a constant. So when your loop is looping from 0...n Console.write is printing the counting value of each loop 1...n+1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got it now